# Парсинг сайта metanit

Tags: c#, .net, парсер, http

Хочу спарсить сайт metanit.com

Стандартными средствами(пример кода https://github.com/extremecodetv/Html-Parser-Tutorial) не выходит. Просто отдает одну пустую страницу.

Пытался использовать `Selenium`, но тоже работает через раз, да и способ этот мне не нравится: ради парсинга целый движок браузера загружать.

Может вы знаете способ лучше? И почему не работает обычный `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` ?

Comment: А что именно вы хотите получить? Попробую поэкспериментировать как будет время.

Comment: что-то подсказывает мне, что вы что-то не так делаете , приведите пример класса или метод запроса.

Comment: Вот тут посмотрите https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NBLGGH57GHF Автор все уже спарсил за вас, осталось отблагодарить и пользоваться.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проверил я данный сайт. Получаете вы не пустую страницу как таковую, а ошибку 403, которая гласит:

> **Access forbidden!**
>   *You don't have permission to access the requested object.
>
>   It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.*

Из за чего это может быть?
Хм, ну по сути это происходит по двум причинам:

1. Вам заблокировали доступ на сервер (или часть сервера)
2. Сервер имеет некую защиту от автоматизации, которая обычно бывает:

   - Банальная проверка *User-Agent* заголовка у запроса.
   - Проверка *Cookie*.
   - Комплексные защиты (CloudFlare например, где используют и то и то сразу (а то и больше...)).

Для начала нам стоит отловить запрос, который мы посылаем при заходе на сервер и по очереди добавлять в наш код все, что необходимо.

Лично я всегда использую подобный код для отправки запросов:

```
public async Task<string> SendRequest(string url)
{
    string data;
    var baseAddress = new Uri("https://metanit.com");
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {
        var result = await client.GetAsync(url);
        data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    return data;
}
```

И так, пробуем по порядку, попробуем задать другой *User-Agent*. Для этого нам достаточно добавить подобную строку до получения `result` переменной:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17120");
```

И о чудо, сервер открыл нам доступ!

Если бы сервер требовал от нас *Cookie*, то стоило бы добавить что то вроде этого до `result`:

```
cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie("key", "value"));
```

В общем, экспериментируйте и смотрите что именно отправляет ваш браузер на сервер, тогда будет в разы легче сделать то, что вы хотите.

Comment: @DigitalCore А вы попробуйте его вообще не задавать, вот просто уберите из приведенного Вами кода строку, которая задает UserAgent. Результатом будет [падение программы с ошибкой 403](https://imgur.com/525mWeX).

Comment: @DigitalCore Это надо уже смотреть что именно требует и как. К примеру DDoS защита от CloudFlare обходится путем генерации определенного url запроса (который содержит в себе определенные ключи полученные при первом заходе) + добавления Cookie (с полученными через запрос) + задержкой в 3 сек.

Comment: EvgeniyZ я уже опубликовал код с обходом клауд :-)

Comment: @DigitalCore Ну, как по мне - использовать Web ядро для парса столь банальных сайтов - это очень не рациональная трата ресурсов. Куда лучше, когда вы все запросы обработаете и отправите сами, а не дадите браузеру. Я лучше напишу небольшой метод, который составит все необходимое, чем поставлю ядро. Но это мое ИМХО, каждый делает то, что умеет и у каждого свой опыт за плечами.

Comment: ИМХО это просто пример и никак не отражает логику и код моих приложений, для таких целей есть написанный парсер, который распознаёт принадлежность ссылок на странице, и умеет отдать деобфусцированный JS вот так.

Comment: @DigitalCore Я вам не про то немного. Я предпочту больше работать с запросами к серверу, который мне отдаст JSON, XML или что то на подобие, чем буду ждать выполнения и парсить HTML c JS. И да, CloudFlare не от Google. Давайте в общем закроем эту дискуссию (а то кучу комментов наплодим), каждый работает по своему)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ класс! Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Приведу пример с `HttpWebRequest` код получен, парсить можно чем угодно дальше.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestParse
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtLog.Text = Parser("https://metanit.com");
        }

        public static string Parser(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request =
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36";

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            output.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
            response.Close();
            return output.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Раз вы упомянули `Selenium` приведу пример с использованием WebDriver с возможностью обхода Cloudflare**

```
public  string GetHtml(string url)
{
    string html = null;
    try
    {
        var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        var Driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService);
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        while (Driver.PageSource.Contains("setTimeout(function()"))
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        html = Driver.PageSource;
        Driver.Close();
        Driver.Quit();
        return html;
    }
    catch { }
      return null;
}
```